# OpenGL export object as .png

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pygame

I've been looking for solution all around the many forums but i didnt find solution for this.
What I want to do is that when I hit enter button it will export my object as 2D image in .png format with transparent background. Object is displayed in pygame window with options to rotate and move it with mouse. So for example I want to rotate and move loaded 3D object and after enter is pressed i want to export as .png.

Code:

```
    # Basic OBJ file viewer. needs objloader from:
#  http://www.pygame.org/wiki/OBJFileLoader
# LMB + move: rotate
# RMB + move: pan
# Scroll wheel: zoom in/out
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.constants import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL import GL
import numpy as np

# IMPORT OBJECT LOADER
from objloader import *
import cv2

pygame.init()
viewport = (800, 600)
hx = viewport[0] / 2
hy = viewport[1] / 2
srf = pygame.display.set_mode(viewport, OPENGL | DOUBLEBUF)

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, (-40, 200, 100, 0.0))
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0))
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0))
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)  # most obj files expect to be smooth-shaded

# LOAD OBJECT AFTER PYGAME INIT
obj = OBJ("mask/surgical_mask_2.obj", swapyz=True)
print(obj)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
width, height = viewport
gluPerspective(90.0, width / float(height), 1, 100.0)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

rx, ry = (0, 0)
tx, ty = (0, 0)
zpos = 5
rotate = move = False
while 1:
    clock.tick(30)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
            buffer = (GL.GLubyte * (3 * 800 * 600))(0)
            img = GL.glReadPixels(0, 0, 800, 600, GL.GL_BGR, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer)
            img = np.array(img)
            cv2.imshow("Output", img)

            k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
            if k == 27:
                break
        elif e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if e.button == 4:
                zpos = max(1, zpos - 1)
            elif e.button == 5:
                zpos += 1
            elif e.button == 1:
                rotate = True
            elif e.button == 3:
                move = True
        elif e.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if e.button == 1:
                rotate = False
            elif e.button == 3:
                move = False
        elif e.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            i, j = e.rel
            if rotate:
                rx += i
                ry += j
            if move:
                tx += i
                ty -= j

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()

    # RENDER OBJECT
    glTranslate(tx / 20., ty / 20., - zpos)
    glRotate(ry, 1, 0, 0)
    glRotate(rx, 0, 1, 0)
    glCallList(obj.gl_list)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

OBJLoader class:

```
import pygame
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *


def MTL(filename):
    contents = {}
    mtl = None
    for line in open(filename, "r"):
        if line.startswith('#'): continue
        values = line.split()
        if not values: continue
        if values[0] == 'newmtl':
            mtl = contents[values[1]] = {}
        elif mtl is None:
            raise (ValueError, "mtl file doesn't start with newmtl stmt")
        elif values[0] == 'map_Kd':
            # load the texture referred to by this declaration
            mtl[values[0]] = values[1]
            print(mtl['map_Kd'])
            surf = pygame.image.load(mtl['map_Kd'])
            image = pygame.image.tostring(surf, 'RGBA', 1)
            ix, iy = surf.get_rect().size
            texid = mtl['texture_Kd'] = glGenTextures(1)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                            GL_LINEAR)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                            GL_LINEAR)
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGBA,
                         GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image)
        else:
            mtl[values[0]] = [float(v) for v in values[1:]]
    return contents


class OBJ:
    def __init__(self, filename, swapyz=False):
        """Loads a Wavefront OBJ file. """
        self.vertices = []
        self.normals = []
        self.texcoords = []
        self.faces = []

        material = None
        for line in open(filename, "r"):
            if line.startswith('#'): continue
            values = line.split()
            if not values: continue
            if values[0] == 'v':
                v = [float(v) for v in values[1:4]]
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.vertices.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vn':
                v = [float(v) for v in values[1:4]]
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.normals.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vt':
                self.texcoords.append([float(v) for v in values[1:3]])
            elif values[0] in ('usemtl', 'usemat'):
                material = values[1]
            elif values[0] == 'mtllib':
                self.mtl = MTL(values[1])
            elif values[0] == 'f':
                face = []
                texcoords = []
                norms = []
                for v in values[1:]:
                    w = v.split('/')
                    face.append(int(w[0]))
                    if len(w) >= 2 and len(w[1]) > 0:
                        texcoords.append(int(w[1]))
                    else:
                        texcoords.append(0)
                    if len(w) >= 3 and len(w[2]) > 0:
                        norms.append(int(w[2]))
                    else:
                        norms.append(0)
                self.faces.append((face, norms, texcoords, material))

        self.gl_list = glGenLists(1)
        glNewList(self.gl_list, GL_COMPILE)
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glFrontFace(GL_CCW)
        for face in self.faces:
            vertices, normals, texture_coords, material = face

            mtl = self.mtl[material]
            if 'texture_Kd' in mtl:
                # use diffuse texmap
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mtl['texture_Kd'])
            else:
                # just use diffuse colour
                glColor3f(*mtl['Kd'])

            glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
            for i in range(len(vertices)):
                if normals[i] > 0:
                    glNormal3fv(self.normals[normals[i] - 1])
                if texture_coords[i] > 0:
                    glTexCoord2fv(self.texcoords[texture_coords[i] - 1])
                glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertices[i] - 1])
            glEnd()
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEndList()
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You already have a handler for the escape key that reads the contents of the screen into a `cv2` image. Copy that and make it save to a PNG on disk and you're done, no?

Comment: it was my first try, but it doesnt work. I just forgot to delete it, sorry.

Comment: No need to be sorry, maybe you just overlooked it. How did it "not work"? How it breaks is often half the answer.

Comment: https://imgur.com/ZQbjPCe
it shows this kind of output